# PostgreSQL 9.1: Find exact expression in title

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I'm looking for a way to search a specific expression - then a part of its - in all documents (and its values associated). The final order should be:

1. Complete expression (in title or content): using ILIKE and '%expression%'
2. One of the word (in title or content): using tsquery on tsvector indexes columns

I have two tables:

- documents (id [integer], title [character varying], title_search [tsvector])
- values (id [integer], content [character varying], content_search [tsvector], id_document [integer])

Here the request I am doing right now:

```
(SELECT id, title, content, title_search, content_search, ts_rank_cd(title_search, query) AS rank
    FROM to_tsquery('lorem&ipsum|(lorem|ipsum)') query, documents
    LEFT JOIN "values" ON id_document=id
    WHERE (title ILIKE(unaccent('%lorem ipsum%')) OR content ILIKE(unaccent('%lorem ipsum%')))) 
 UNION (SELECT id, title, content, title_search, content_search, ts_rank_cd(title_search, query) AS rank
    FROM to_tsquery('lorem&ipsum|(lorem|ipsum)') query, documents
    LEFT JOIN "values" ON id_document=id
    WHERE query @@ title_search)
 UNION (SELECT id, title, content, title_search, content_search, ts_rank_cd(title_search, query) AS rank
    FROM to_tsquery('lorem&ipsum|(lorem|ipsum)') query, documents
    LEFT JOIN "values" ON id_document=id
    WHERE query @@ content_search) 
 ORDER BY rank DESC, title ASC
```

By doing this, I can get all documents with this expression and/or a part of its but I can't get to have those correctly ordrered. This is because I am relying on ranking with ts_rank on tsvector field which cannot be used to define exact expression.

So my questions are how I can get this to work as I expect? Am I wrong for using full text search?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit awkward but a solution I've used before is to include an extra "rank" column in your individual subqueries. For instance, the fist query would look like

```
select 1 as which_rank, id, title, ...
....
where title ILIKE(unaccent('%lorem ipsum%'))
   OR content ILIKE(unaccent('%lorem ipsum%')))
```

then the second would be

```
select 2 as which_rank, id, title, ...
...
where query @@ title_search
```

and the third would be

```
select 3 as which_rank, id, title, ...
...
where query @@ content_search
```

If you include that ranking value in your sort order:

```
ORDER BY which_rank asc, rank DESC, title ASC
```

you can make sure the first case gets listed first, the second second, and the third third. You can also re-arrange which is 1, 2, 3 depending on your needs.